# NTLM authentication failing

Tags: java, authentication, ntlm

I'm trying to get NTLM authentication working in some Java code, but getting 401'd.

[This page](https://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html) makes me think the following code (source for NTLMEngineImpl is from Apache HTTPClient and modified slightly [here](https://github.com/richmidwinter/okhttp-ntlm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/surevine/okhttp/NTLMEngineImpl.java)):

```
System.out.println(new NTLMEngineImpl().generateType3Msg("Zaphod", "Beeblebrox", "Ursa-Minor", "LightCity", "TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAAAAAACgAAAABggAAU3J2Tm9uY2UAAAAAAAAAAA=="));
```

Should output:

```
TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHIAAAAYABgAigAAABQAFABAAAAADAAMAFQAAAASABIAYAAAAAAAAACiAAAAAYIAAFUAUgBTAEEALQBNAEkATgBPAFIAWgBhAHAAaABvAGQATABJAEcASABUAEMASQBUAFkArYfKbe/jRoW5xDxHeoxC1gBmfWiS5+iX4OAN4xBKG/IFPwfH3agtPEia6YnhsADT
```

Instead I get:

```
TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAEgAAAAYABgAYAAAABQAFAB4AAAADAAMAIwAAAASABIAmAAAAAAAAACqAAAAAYIAAgUBKAoAAAAPrYfKbe/jRoW5xDxHeoxC1gBmfWiS5+iX4OAN4xBKG/IFPwfH3agtPEia6YnhsADTVQBSAFMAQQAtAE0ASQBOAE8AUgBaAGEAcABoAG8AZABMAGkAZwBoAHQAQwBpAHQAeQA=
```

Which looks close - I think the expected string is almost, but not quite, a substring of the actual string. So where does the extra data come from and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find an adequate solution?  I am getting SSLHandshakeException